# Reaching unexpected tweet limit in twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I have paid premium access to Twitter so can access historical data. I am trying to retrieve tweets on a combined search for the terms 'delivery' and 'accident', ie as if I go to a Twitter search and type 'delivery accident' or 'delivery+accident' in the 'latest' tab. My code for doing so is the following:

```
deliv_list <- searchTwitter("delivery+accident", n=500)
```

I am getting results which correspond to my search, but far fewer than I had expected. R returns the error message:

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 248
```

I subsequently checked and I am able to return 500 records for a different single search, so it is not that I have reached a download limit. There are multiple tweets every day on this theme so I'm not sure why so few results n=248 are returned. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps there are only 248 tweets available for the search? You can sanity check this by trying to return 500 tweets for a topic that you are certain has > 500 tweets (e.g., see what's trending today and try to search for that).

Comment: Well, there are more than 300 tweets on this word combination since the beginning of February. I also tried to send the results to an RSQLite database via DBI using search_twitter_and_store() but also with no success (same number of tweets were retrieved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems twitteR cannot handle full archive premium accounts. search-tweets-python seems to be the way to go. Tantalizingly, this may be able to work inside R via R's reticulate package. See: https://dev.to/twitterdev/running-search-tweets-python-in-r-45eo